# Is there an option to deactivate style cop rule without making an "GlobalSuppressions.cs" file?

Tags: c#, stylecop

We use StyleCop Analyzer in our project. One of my tasks is to deactivate a few rules, but without creating a `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file.

I found solutions, but only with creating this file, so I'm confused.

Comment: If all the solutions you find tell you to create such a file ..... maybe it's because that's the only way to achieve this...... so why are you so *against* creating that file?? What's the problem with having that additional file??

Comment: My supervisor suggest me to delete that files, so i look for solution. If it`s impossible, I will accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To suppress a warning outside of `GlobalSuppressions.cs`, you can either:

Use comments (remember to restore the warnings out of the scope!)

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0052 // Remove unread private members
private readonly Object _obj;
#pragma warning restore IDE0052 // Remove unread private members
```

or use the `SuppressMessage` attribute in place

```
[SuppressMessage("Code Quality", "IDE0052:Remove unread private members", Justification = "<Pending>")]
private readonly Object _obj;
```

If you want to disable them globally, you can use an [.editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options) file at the root of your solution.

```
root = true
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0052.severity = none
```

You can also configure a Ruleset file, but **this is now deprecated**.

In your csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>File.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then create `File.ruleset` as your per your need. It looks roughly like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules" Description="These rules focus on the most critical problems in your code, including potential security holes, application crashes, and other important logic and design errors. It is recommended to include this rule set in any custom rule set you create for your projects." ToolsVersion="10.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers">
    <Rule Id="CA1056" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

More details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#rule-sets